# Contenido diferente de acuerdo a la url, angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Quisiera saber como se llama o como  se hace la funcionalidad, para por medio de la url controlar el contenido, por ejemplo algo como facebook, que maneja el perfil desde la url: www.facebook.com/perfil.persona y en base a perfil.persona le muestra toda esa información.

Quisiera implementarlo en una web que tengo con angularjs spa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás buscando algo como esto?

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        .when('/contact/:id', {
            templateUrl : 'contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
});

app.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
});

app.controller('contactController', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
   function ($scope, $routeParams) {
     //Obtenés un id desde la URL
     var currentId = $routeParams.id;
}]);
```

Desde el html, podés navegar así:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <!-- En este link podés pasar el id que necesites -->
    <li><a href="#contact/1">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Espero que te sirva.
Saludos

Comment: Excelente, desde aqui lo controlo entonces, por otro lado, que tendria que hacer para que mi url se vea asi: mipagina.com/pagina-compartir-facebook, es decir el parametro entre "-" guión medio.

Comment: El parámetro lo podés definir como a vos mas te sirva. Se puede generar automáticamente por nombre de usuario y agregarlo a la URL. El $routeParams tiene la propiedad que definas en la configuración, y luego puede contener lo que vos necesites.

Comment: Sabras de una libreria que lo haga ? muchas gracias. saludos ¡¡

Comment: Que necesitás específicamente? porque no necesitaría librerías, con solo hacer una función que arme el path, y usando $location.path('/ruta/nombre-apellido'); dentro de la función, ya tendrías algo que te redireccione a donde vos necesites

Comment: Algo asi,  https://github.com/garrettmac/angular-slugs , que por lo que ve, se usa para el SEO tambien el termino de Slugs